# Compiling Error in linux LXTerminal using raspberry pi

Tags: command-line, raspberry-pi

I have installed wiringpi library using this link [here](http://wiringpi.com/download-and-install/) . I'm trying to compile and run the example file blink.c but i can't get it to compile. Here is what I have done already. I have searched for threads involving this issue but i can't find a solution.

Here is what I have done already

sudo gcc -Wall blink.c -o blink

this command returns the following error.

/tmp/ccAYNTuE.o: In function ‘main’:

blink.c:(.text+0x10) : undefined reference to ‘wiringPiSetup’

blink.c:(.text+0x1c) : undefined reference to ‘pinMode’

blink.c:(.text+0x28) : undefined reference to ‘digitalwrite’

blink.c:(.text+0x30) : undefined reference to ‘delay’

blink.c:(.text+0x3c) : undefined reference to ‘wiringPiSetup’

blink.c:(.text+0x44) : undefined reference to ‘delay’

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I changed file permissions to 755 but didn't do any good. So after I searched some ideas I came across a thread that said to use g++ instead of gcc so I tried that and received the same error above.

I tired not typing sudo this time also and got this

/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file blink: Permission denied

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also is the command different for compiling C version files from C++ versions?

Answer (score 0):

try  gcc -Wall blink.c -o blink -lwiringPi

Answer (score 0):

enter into root..
then move to your directory then type
g++ -o blink blink.c -lwiringPi
once compiled..
run your executable by
./blink
try this.. hope it works for you..